# SwiftUI how to center position an item in VStack

Tags: swiftui

I have a simple view like this:

```
    let state = viewModel.state
    
    VStack {
    
      // "Come back tomorrow!" label
      Text(loc(.comeBackTomorrow))
        .withMainBodyStyle()
    
      if state.isRewardable && viewModel.isVideoAdReady {

        // "One more joke?" button
        SUIBorderedTextButton(
          title: loc(.oneMoreJokeButtonTitle),
          fontSize: font_size_one_more_joke_button,
          backgroundColor: color_one_more_joke_button,
          enabled: true)
        {
          AdUtil.showVideoAd()
        }
      }
    }
```

This code is the content region in this screenshot, excluding the toolbar on the bottom:

[image]

Note that "Come back tomorrow!" label is roughly positioned at 1/3 of the VStack, and "One more joke?" button is roughly at 2/3 of the VStack.

Now I need to position VStack items such that "Come back tomorrow!" label is in the center of the VStack, and "One more joke?" button is slightly below "Come back tomorrow!" label. How can I do that?

Edit:

I tried this code in the answer by @Asperi:

```
VStack {
  Spacer()

  Text("Label")    // << your label view here

  Spacer().overlay(Group {
     if condition {
        Button("Title") {}     // << your button here 
     }
  }, alignment: .top)

}
```

And got this result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach is to use `Color.clear` and `overlay`, like

```
VStack {
  Color.clear

  Text("Label")    // << your label view here

  Color.clear.overlay(Group {
     if condition {
        Button("Title") {}     // << your button here 
     }
  }, alignment: .top)

}
```

Comment: The button's size is distorted to take the whole bottom Spacer, and width is distorted to be very small

Comment: added a screenshot to show the result

Comment: Seems they changed Spacer behavior, see updated with Color.clear. Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

Comment: wow `Color.clear` works. Can you explain a bit about your solution?

Comment: why Spacer() does not work? what's the diff between Spacer() and Color.clear?

Comment: Color fills all available space (in this case equally above and below Text) but Spacer only by axis of parent container (column in this case).